# Как в php загрузить несколько файлов из формы?

Tags: php, jquery

Если я пытаюсь загрузить с помощью такой формы несколько файлов на сервер, то `var_dump($_FILES)` выдает `empty`. Если загружаю один файл - то все в порядке.
Вопрос: как загрузить несколько файлов на сервер, и как к ним обратится из `PHP` и из `jQuery` ?
HTML code:

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="userFile" multiple>
<button type="submit">Submit </button>
```

Comment: мне лень проверять, чтобы писать ответ, но разве вы не пихаете в userfile, который не является массивом, собственно массив из нескольких файлов? попробуйте userFile[] написать и гляньте что будет

Comment: Да, пробовал и так, но поведение было очень странное. То загружалось, то нет. Потом понял, что дело в настройках php.ini  `post_max_size` и  `upload_max_filesize`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для тех кто столкнется с проблемой загрузки нескольких файлов на сервер:
В php.ini есть две директивы `upload_max_filesize` и `post_max_size`. Так вот, первой мы задаём максимальный размер одного загружаемого файла. А второй максимальный размер который можно передать методом POST. Соответственно, если вы хотите загрузить 3 файла по 5mb, то как минимум:
`upload_max_filesize = 5М`
 `post_max_size = 15М`
Причём, если суммарный вес ваших файлов окажется более того что указан в `post_max_size`, то все данные передаваемые методом POST потеряются и оба массива будут пусты
`$_POST == empty`
`$_FILES == empty`
Лично меня это очень сбило с толку :)
Ну и да, как ответили в комментариях - в `html` форме мы задаем имя input'a массивом, т.е. : `name="userFiles[]"`